# write data to oracle database, but first check it in mapping table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, mapping

Here is what I want to do:

I have 2 tables in oracle database. First one for my data, and second for mapping.

Mapping table has 2 columns and it's like this:

```
olive - green
marine - green
grass - green
green - green
navy - blue
sky - blue
light blue - blue
```

etc.

First table (for my data) has more columns, and I should fill every row in that table with various number of colors from mapping table.

and I have txt file with this:

```
olive, 
navy,
green,
#
blue,
sky,
olive,
marine,
#
blue,
light blue,
#
```

etc.

So, I should basically write that data to my first table in database, but not with those values from txt file, but with adequate value from mapping table.

I hope I explained it well enough. Help pls?

Comment: No, you have not explained it well enough.  However, you can create an external table to reference a formatted text file as a table, and query it.

Comment: So... you want to translate the value from the file to the one that's mapped in the table; so if the file has `olive` you insert `green`? How are you reading the text file, and how do the entries in that correspond to the existing rows in your data table?

Comment: Alex, yes, that's what I want to do. My data table is empty at the moment, and I'm not sure how to make it possible to read the text file and do what I want to do.

OldProgrammer, are you are saying that I should make another table and insert data from txt file there, and then somehow try to compare it to my data in mapping table? I could try that.

Comment: You can create an external table to a file in oracle ( go read the documentation on external tables).

Comment: @OldProgrammer I forgot to say thanks once again, external tables solved half of the problem, and I did rest with simple plsql code. Solved! :)